# Is lowered probability of spending equals savings?

Tags: finance, probability, saving

This a really basic one and logic says: Yes given enough iterations.
But I am looking for validation

Situation: There is a 7% probability of expenses of 1000 occurring. I have a tool that then applied to the process has a 95% probability to reduce the chance of expenses occurring by 58-78% (mean at 60%). 
How do I calculate savings?

Comment: This needs to be better phrased. How much agent's save will be determined by their preferences for risk. A more risk-adverse agent will save to cover more than the expected loss, while the risk-neutral agent will save to cover his expected loss.

Comment: Fair point. In this instance it's government... I would classify as risk-neutral. Could you please give samples for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going into Risk-Adverse case as this is sensitive to how we define the Government's utility function

$\mathbb{E}[xpnse] = 0.05*(0.07*1000)+0.95*(0.6*(0.07*1000))$

Follows from Law of Large Numbers